# JPA Exception Translation in Java EE Container

Tags: hibernate, jakarta-ee, jpa, jta

Is there an easy way to translate JPA Exceptions to application exceptions?

My Remote Session Bean in a Java EE Container (JBoss) is called by the client via RMI. The Session Bean gets a JPA Entity Manager injected and is writing something into the database. Transactions are handled by the container (JTA). If any exception occurs when writing to the database then this exception is thrown to the client. Since I'm using Hibernate I've got Hibernate Exceptions in the client. The client does not know any Hibernate libs and therefore I'm getting ClassNotFoundExceptions in the client. Now I would like to translate the exception in the container and throw an exception that my client can handle.  I had the following ideas but all of them have a drawback I think:

1. Avoid the JPA Exception e.g. by checking constraints before writing to the database. This means to duplicate DB constraints in business logic.
2. Flushing the Entity Manager inside the business method and catching and translating any errors that might be raised during flush inside the method. Well, I like the idea that the Persistence Provider postpones any talking to the database as long as possible.
3. Disabling Container Managed Transactions and doing transaction management in my own Interceptor. This way I can catch all exceptions that occur before or during commit and wrap them to my application exceptions.
4. Use Spring JPA and Springs Exception Translation features. Well I'm already in a Java EE Container maybe there is some Java EE way to do Exception Translation?

Answer (score 0):

My advice is to give the Hibernate libraries to the client, and tell the client not to use them (except for debugging).

This is an example of the well known complaint that exceptions break encapsulation.

Answer (score 0):

You could also try-catch `org.hibernate.HibernateException` in all methods that can be called directly by the client and re-throw another Exception

Comment: Well, I can't use try-catch on server side since the transaction is managed by the JEE container and I cannot catch any exception that is thrown outside my business logic. I could catch the Hibernate Exception on client side but that menas giving the Hibernate and database driver libraries to the client.